# How to inject a service into a symfony command?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have this basic Symfony command class

```
class MyCommand extends Command
{

    protected EntityManagerInterface $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('my:command')
            ->setDescription('what my command does');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        echo 'Hello World';
    }

}
```

if I run bin/console my:command I get an error saying the command does not exists.

If I comment out the constructor then I can see the output. `autoconfigure` and `autowire` are set to true.

this is services.yml:

```yaml
_defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
```

same thing if I use

```yaml
my_command:
        class: Path\To\MyCommand
        arguments:
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Comment: With the constructor added back in, does 'bin/console debug:container MyCommand' show the expected info including the console.command tag?

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache?

Comment: no, I get "No services found that match "MyCommand"

Comment: yes I also cleared the cache

Comment: Okay.  So the basic issue is that your command is not being picked up as a service.  Which it should be if you are using the out of the box config/services.yaml file.  Consider updating your question and show config/services.yaml.  I suspect this is a legacy app upgraded from a much earlier Symfony version?

Comment: I see your update and I could post an answer but this question is basically a typo.  You need to add the ['resource' section](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container) to services.yaml in order to automatically define services.  Your manual definition would also have worked if you had tagged it properly.  The docs discuss tagging as well.

Comment: do I really need the command to be a service to inject other services into it?

Comment: The command needs to be a service (tagged with console.command) in order for the console executable to know about it.  That explains the original 'command does not exist' message.  And yes something has to be a service in order to inject other services into it.  As a historical note, back in the days of Symfony 2.x commands were not routinely defined as services.  Instead, any classes in the Command directory were treated as commands.  But those days are long gone.

Comment: solved using "resource". thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Looks like the way you have written your property is wrong. Can you change it from:

```
protected EntityManagerInterface $em;
```

to:

```
protected $em;
```

and try again.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what exactly do you think that will accomplish?

Comment: What makes you think that this is wrong? If it was, why should Symfony complain about a non-existing command?